# Not able to add implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'

Tags: kotlin, google-places-api, androidx

I am trying to add Places SDK for android.

I am following the following documentation
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start and
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Unfortunately i am not able to add dependency "implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'"

I have gone through following links. But no use. Please help me with this.

[Failed to resolve: com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878944/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-libraries-places1-0-0)

[Google's new Places Library ( implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0') not resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484585/googles-new-places-library-implementation-com-google-android-libraries-place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution to my issue.

I solved it by installing the compatibility library.

Followed this. https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Following two steps resolved my issue.

1. Copy the contents of places_compat_compatify.sh, and save as a file to your local computer.
2. Use the following command to run the compatibility script

   ./places_compat_compatify.sh  2.1.0

After this, I could run my project successfully and could Place API.

Thanks